# PHP - Using cURL to get the final URL status after redirect

Tags: php, php-curl

I am using this function to get the status of the final URL after some possible redirects:

```
function getUrlStatus($url) {
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);    // we want headers
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    
        curl_exec($ch);

        $httpStatus = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $redirectURL = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL);
        curl_close($ch);

        if($httpStatus >= 300 && $httpStatus < 400) {
            getUrlStatus($redirectURL);
        } else {
            return $httpStatus;
        }
    }
```

If the first URL I check is not redirected, this works fine and displays the status, but if there is a redirected URL which is being checked (so the `getUrlStatus` function is called recursively), the result seems to be `NULL`:

```
var_dump(getUrlStatus($url));   //   NULL
```

I am doing this check for multiple URLs and all of them have the status 307, so they are all calling again the function so `NULL` is being displayed. Please advise what am I doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for 
`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`

`TRUE to follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header (note this is recursive, PHP will follow as many "Location: " headers that it is sent, unless CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS is set).`

from: http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.curl-setopt.php

If you don't plan to use the option `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` then you must make sure you're analyzign the headers correctly to get the status.
From `http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php` you can see 

`CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE - The last response code.(...)`

that means: there can be more than one status code.
i.e with `http://airbrake.io/login` there are two sent:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
(...)

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
(...)
```

That means, only 200 is going to be returned, and if you want to get ANY result, your function needs to look like:

```
 if($httpStatus >= 300 && $httpStatus < 400) {
     return getUrlStatus($redirectURL);
 } else {
     return $httpStatus;
 }
```

Comment: I tried to use this, but the page gets changed and I don't want it to behave like this. I need to check a list of URLs and display their final statuses (after multiple redirects) into the page page.

Comment: then I think you need to provide the URL you're running your function against, the current result and expected result. Only when we can reproduce the issue, we can help you.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot give you the exact URLs I am testing because they contain some sensitive information, but you can check it with any 3xx URL, for example: `http://airbrake.io/login` which normally returns a 301 status. 
`$test = getUrlStatus('http://airbrake.io/login');   var_dump($test);  // NULL`
Thanks for your help!

Comment: if I use the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`, I get `200`.
If I don't use `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` I get `NULL`.

Comment: Right, because there is a 301 redirect on the first call and if you use `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` you get the final destination URL status. So this could be a solution, but as I said, I cannot use `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` because the page gets redirected and I need to avoid this. I am struggling to understand why my function returns and empty result when it should call itself again until the HTTP status is 200 (in this case).

Comment: so what is the result you expect to get from querying `http://airbrake.io/login`? You didn't provide the expected result so far.